# Jenkins groovy - How to retrieve tag from latest commit?

Tags: git, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, git-tag, jenkins-groovy

To fetch the latest commit from `branchName`, we run below code:

```
treeMapData = git(branch: branchName, credentialsId: credential, url: "${gitLabServer}/${projectName}/${repo}.git")
```

---

It is ensured that there is one tag per commit, as per our workflow

We want to build the code, only if the commit is tagged.

---

How to retrieve the tag name for that latest commit?

Comment: I’ve done exactly this. If you can wait until Monday, please remind me and I’ll answer this question with my approach.

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/alpine/semver

Answer (score 6):

We can fetch the tags from the repo in case Jenkins hasn't already.

```
git fetch --tags
```

We need to find a tag(s) which point to a specific commit or `HEAD` in our case. Thankfully there is a handy command in git which allows us to do this.

```
git tag --points-at HEAD
```

Using `awk` we can turn this into an output which groovy can falsify.

```
awk NF
```

---

So we, first we check if the pushed branch is master

```
if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
```

lock it down

```
  lock('publish master') {
```

execute the git tag shell script and assign it to TAG

```
    TAG = sh (
      returnStdout: true,
      script: 'git fetch --tags && git tag --points-at HEAD | awk NF'
    ).trim()
```

if a tag exists, do something!

```
    if (TAG) {
      stage('Deploy Prod') {
        echo "Deploying to Prod ${TAG}"
      }
    }
```

---

Hopefully this answers your question, or at the very least will get you on the right track.

Comment: If my single  pipeline is mapped to multiple repo, does `env` have repo name that had push/merge event of new commit? Like `env.BRANCH_NAME` gives the branch name pushed to...

Comment: You can find the environment variables your jenkins supports by going to https://my.jenkins.hostname/env-vars.html --- My Jenkins installation has an `env.GIT_URL` variable.

Comment: If one of the.multiple repo create push/merge event, then, does `env.GIT_URL` shows the repository that triggered the pipeline?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. We use one pipeline for each repo. When you test, please let me know!

Comment: Is `env.BRANCH_NAME` a global environment variable? Or environment variable specific to that pipeline?

Comment: I would assume it’s per pipeline, but I’m not sure.

Comment: But, can we run `git fetch --tags` directly? How can I run this command directly? without cloning the repo... BTW, we are not cloning the repo...

Comment: You can execute a shell script directly using the `sh()` function.

Comment: Without setting the `git remote`, how can we run `git fetch --tags`? Are you saying that `git remote` will be sett though webhook?

Comment: I don't think you can. Git wouldn't know where to fetch from. How are you getting the latest code without a remote?

Comment: After I know the tag, how does groovy script checkout the tag?

Comment: In my pipeline it doesn’t. It only gets the tag which points to HEAD which by definition is already checked out. If you need to checkout the tag, use `git checkout ${TAG}`.

Comment: For your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54949432/jenkins-groovy-how-to-retrieve-tag-from-latest-commit#comment96729266_54981344), I tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55025020/how-to-retrieve-git-url-on-web-hook), but no luck.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what's the point of `| awk NF`? That just prints each non-blank input line. I admit I don't understand groovy at all (the language seems very weird).

Comment: @torek I can't actually remember now. I think it might have been to remove the less pager, but I now know you can do that with the `--no-pager` flag.

Comment: Ah. Well, presumably `git tags` run from within Groovy shouldn't think it has a tty unless Groovy gives all of its commands psedo-ttys, which would be a horrible idea and therefore typical of Groovy. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone needs this (like I did):
you need to build from a tag, not from a commit. Then env.TAG_NAME becomes available and you can write code like this:

```
if(env.TAG_NAME) {
    ...
}
```